# removeClass() method is not working to remove css which is applied on div

Tags: jquery

I applied css on div by using class and I want to remove applied css by using removeClass() method of jQuery

How can I remove applied class of css by using removeClass()

removeClass() method applied but it is not removing class css after clicking on div

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("div.one").css({
    backgroundColor: 'aqua',
    color: 'black'
  });

  $("div.two").css({
    backgroundColor: 'lightpink',
    color: 'black'
  });

  $("div.three").css({
    backgroundColor: 'lightgreen',
    color: 'black'
  });

  $("div.one").click(function() {

    $("div.one").removeClass("one");

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="one" id="firstId">
  <p>Heloo first div</p>
</div>
<div class="two" id="secondId">
  <p>Hello second div</p>
</div>
<div class="three" id="thirdId">
  <p>Hello third div</p>
</div>
<h1 style="color: green;">You can remove color if you don't want</h1>
```

after clicking on the div it should remove applied css class and  make that div normal.

Comment: Your function works fine, just that the css is not bound to the class `one` but directly applied to the one div via inline styling through the `.css` function

Answer (score 0):

That's because your css is getting added to element when you apply that using jquery. Define the style in CSS and it should work properly:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

   $("div.one").click(function() {

    $("div.one").removeClass("one");

  });

});
```

```css
div.one
{
 background-color: aqua;
 color: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="one" id="firstId">
  <p>Heloo first div</p>
</div>
<div class="two" id="secondId">
  <p>Hello second div</p>
</div>
<div class="three" id="thirdId">
  <p>Hello third div</p>
</div>
<h1 style="color: green;">You can remove color if you don't want</h1>
```

Comment: Or remove the `style` attribute instead of a `class`.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the css with jQuery.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("div.one").css({
    backgroundColor: 'aqua',
    color: 'black'
  });

  $(".two").css({
    backgroundColor: 'lightpink',
    color: 'black'
  });

  $(".three").css({
    backgroundColor: 'lightgreen',
    color: 'black'
  });

  $("#firstId").click(function() {
    $("#firstId").css("background-color", "");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="one" id="firstId">
  <p>Hello first div</p>
</div>

<div class="two" id="secondId">
  <p>Hello second div</p>
</div>

<div class="three" id="thirdId">
  <p>Hello third div</p>
</div>

<h1 style="color: green;">You can remove color if you don't want</h1>
```